# Display Sharepoint Webpart as a PopUp

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I need to display SharePoint WebPart in a PopUp.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create a regular web part page, but base it on an empty master page, the result will be the same, but more customizable.
You can also maybe use a hidden DIV with a web part zone, if you need an overlay section and don't care if it's not an actual window

Comment: Thanks Vladi. These looks like something achievable. Could you provide any references on these techniques.

Comment: for the first one - just create an empty master page: http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/BaseMasterPages.aspx
For the second solution - in SPD wrap a web part zone in;
<div id="yourID" style="display:none;position:absolute; top:[value]px;left:[value]px;so on...">

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom application page (in _layouts) without any menu or navigation, then add a webpart into it and open that page as your popup.

Comment: Thanks Nico... How do I add a WebPart to an application page? Sorry about my ignorance. I haven't done it and couldnt find any sample on web.